# Return a one-element list from a multi-element list of strings

Tags: python, string, list, function, python-3.x

```
region = str(shakeInstance[7:])
```

returns the 7th, 8th…string elements of a list:

```
['NEW', 'BRITAIN', 'REGION,', 'PAPUA', 'NEW', ‘GUINEA']
```

I’m trying to return a list with one (str) element, i.e.:

```
join(region)
```

would return:

```
[‘NEW BRITAIN REGION PAPUA NEW GUINEA’]
```

Is there way to do this (I'm new to programming) in Python 3? I’m trying to avoid iterating and concatenation. I'm sure someone has rolled their own function to do this but I have had no luck finding it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> ' '.join(['NEW', 'BRITAIN', 'REGION,', 'PAPUA', 'NEW', 'GUINEA'])
'NEW BRITAIN REGION, PAPUA NEW GUINEA'
```

---

```
region = ' '.join(shakeInstance[7:])
```